# How do I get average of data in pandas including the blank cells?

Tags: python, pandas

I have some students data that I need to get average.
What I've realized is that when I work it out in pandas, I get the average as according to the number  of subjects done by a student, it it doesn't include those subjects that the student didn't sit for. I however, need it to work out the average using the total number of subjects in that class(including those the student didn't sit for).
Is this even possible??

```
df["AVE"] = df[column_list].mean(axis=1).round(decimals=0)
```

Comment: Let me see what this does. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace missing values by `0` by [`DataFrame.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'A':list('abcdef'),
         'B':[np.nan,5,np.nan,5,5,np.nan],
         'C':[7,8,9,np.nan,2,3],
         'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
         'E':[5,3,6,9,2,np.nan],
         'F':list('aaabbb')
})
column_list = ['B','C','D']
df["AVE1"] = df[column_list].mean(axis=1).round(decimals=0)
df["AVE2"] = df[column_list].fillna(0).mean(axis=1).round(decimals=0)
print (df)
   A    B    C  D    E  F  AVE1  AVE2
0  a  NaN  7.0  1  5.0  a   4.0   3.0
1  b  5.0  8.0  3  3.0  a   5.0   5.0
2  c  NaN  9.0  5  6.0  a   7.0   5.0
3  d  5.0  NaN  7  9.0  b   6.0   4.0
4  e  5.0  2.0  1  2.0  b   3.0   3.0
5  f  NaN  3.0  0  NaN  b   2.0   1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for this has done it well.

```
df["AVE"] = df[column_list].fillna(0).mean(axis=1).round(decimals=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return NaN when there is a NaN, as in Numpy mean(), you can use skipna argument for skeeping/not skeeping, NA/null values. By default this argument is set to True:

```
df["AVE"] = df[column_list].mean(axis=1, skipna=False).round(decimals=0)
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html

Comment: This hasn't done for me what I expected it to do. It has not worked out the average for cells with blanks.

Comment: Right. skipna= will return NaN if there is a NaN. It permits to have the same behavior as with Numpy mean().  I edit my message.